# Scrapy cannot find inside <div> tags

Tags: python, html, scrapy

good day. I'm currently writing a Scrapy program to **scrape** a news website. I'm a beginner in Scrapy, and I've come into a bump that unable me to progress in my code.

The website that I'm currrently trying to **scrape** is https://www.thestar.com.my/news/nation

Inside the page's html tags, there's a ***div*** tag with **class="row list-listing"**. I'm trying to get the ***paragraph*** tag inside the ***div*** tag, but somehow Scrapy can't seem to find the tag.

I've checked for the any not closed tags, but all of them seem to be closed. So why did Scrapy unable to fetch this tag? The most inner tag that Scrapy can fetch is **div class="sub-section-list"** which is outside the **div class="row list-listing"**

Also, when I fetch the **div class="sub-section-list"** tag, it only extract these html tags:

```html
"<div class=""sub-section-list"">
     <div class=""button-view btnLoadMore"" style=""margin: 10px auto 15px;"">
         <a id=""loadMorestories"">Load more </a>
     </div>
 </div>"
```

When inspecting the website, there are these tags that I need

[Website Tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byf1r.png)

I will include my basic code. I've only started the project so I haven't made any progress since this problem.

```html
import scrapy


class WebCrawl(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spooder"
    allowed_domains = ["thestar.com.my"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.thestar.com.my/news/nation"]

    def parse(self, response):
        text = response.xpath("//div[@class='sub-section-list']").extract()
        yield {
            'text' : text
        }
```

If I forgot to add any other necessary things please tell. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As Wim says the page is being loaded dynamically so there are [a few options](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html).
Using Firefox developer tools it looks like the content is being retrieved from:

```
https://cdn.thestar.com.my/Content/Data/parsely_data.json
```

So you could directly load the json and get what you want from there. Something like:

```
import scrapy
import json

class WebCrawl(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spooder"
    allowed_domains = ["thestar.com.my"]
    start_urls = ["https://cdn.thestar.com.my/Content/Data/parsely_data.json"]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield from json.loads(response.text)['data']
```

Of course, this probably isn't exactly what you want, but perhaps it is a good start?

*(Note that the above code is overkill for what it does, but if you are going to start some scraping you can work from that)*

Comment: Yes. Your code was very helpful to kickstart back this problem for me to progress. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The content is loaded dynamically so you won't be able to use xpath like this without rendering the page. It seems the article bodies are present in the html, and you can get it as follows:

```
import json
script = response.xpath(
  "//script[contains(text(), 'var listing = ')]/text()"
).extract_first()

first_index = script.index('var listing = ') + len('var listing = ')
last_index = script.index('};') + 1
listings = json.loads(script[first_index:last_index])
articles = [article['article_body'] for article in listings['data']]
```

Comment: Wow I did not know you can extract the data through this. Thank you for your help. It was very helpful :)